# How do I pull phoneNumber from Linkedin Javascript API array

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api

I appreciate any help with those familiar with the LinkedIn JavaScript API. Question: How do I pull in the phone number and email from the field array. In my example, posted to a php script, both phoneNumber and emailAddress are undefined when set to $_POST[''];:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //Runs when the JavaScript framework is loaded
function onLinkedInLoad() {
IN.UI.Authorize().params({"scope":["r_fullprofile", "r_emailaddress", "r_contactinfo"]}).place();
IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", onLinkedInAuth);
 }

  //Runs when the viewer has authenticated
  function onLinkedInAuth() {

   IN.API.Profile("me").fields("id,firstName,lastName,phoneNumbers,emailAddress,positions").result(displayProfiles);

}

 // 2. Runs when the Profile() API call  returns successfully
  function displayProfiles(profiles) {
var p = profiles.values[0]; 

var phone = profiles.values[0].phoneNumbers;

for (var i in p.positions.values) {
    var pos = p.positions.values[i];
    if (pos.isCurrent)
        var company = pos.company.name;
}

 //AJAX call to pass back vars to server
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var postdata= "id=" + p.id + "&fName=" + p.firstName + "&lName=" + p.lastName + "&phone=" + phone + "&email1=" + p.emailAddress + "&company=" + company;
http.open("POST", "../inc/linkedin.php", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

use fields like this http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields
Try this...

```
IN.API.Profile("me")
        .fields('id,email-address,first-name,last-name,date-of-birth,phone-numbers,positions,num-connections')
        .result(displayProfiles)
        .error(displayErrors);
```

Comment: Thank you; however, same results. Using my code as the example, and getting no console errors, I get undefined for both email and phone. It may be that because a Linked in user has not given those values they are undefined. I'll keep working on it. Phone may be a problem as I do not know how to define phoneNumbers then phoneNumber then work phone number in my array.